# newtype and recursive definition

Tags: haskell, recursion

```
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a,String)])
```

Hi, Let's consider above definition:
On my eye it is infinite definition- recursive definition. For example I defined tree ( recursive, infinite structures) like:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) (Tree a).
```

And `Tree` can be inifinite but we have `Leaf` and it can "finish" recursive definition. So, let's translate my first definition to `data`:
( just replace newtype- according to https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype )

```
data Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a,String)])
```

And it is recursive definition and there is no "finite element" like `Leaf`. How to understand it?

Comment: where is that a recursion? you define a type  (constructor) "Parser" with a (data) constructor "Parser". The defined type does not occur on the right.

Comment: `data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) (Tree a).` Is there here recursion?

Comment: Also, semantically, there is no difference between `newtype` and `data` so you haven't really done anything different.

Comment: Also, your Tree definition doesn't make use of the parametrized variable `a`. It is recursive though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Parser definition is not actually recursive. On the right of the `=` sign is [constructor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor). Constructors can have the same name as their type but the two things are separate concepts.

You could call the parser constructor something else without losing any functionality:

```haskell
data Parser a = Foo (String -> [(a, String)])
```

Your `Tree` type has two constructors, `Leaf` and `Node`. The thing that makes it recursive is that the definition of `Node` recursively includes two type parameters, both of which are `Tree`.